# Living at house number X

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, american-english

Is it natural to say in American English, "I live at house #7"?

What about a character introduced as "the lady who lives at house #7"?
The characters say the numbers because all of them are tenants of a small community with a shared gate and a patio. The "houses" are like apartments but on the ground level.

Is there a more concise way to say that without adding "who live(s)"?

Comment: It isn't wrong but it doesn't sound completely natural to me either.  We don't usually say "**house** number 7", just "number 7".  But it also sounds odd to just say "I live at number 7."  It would make me say "Number seven what?"  We usually say addresses like "I live at fifty-six Elm Street."

Comment: Usually, you would need the street as well as the number, and you wouldn't say "number": "I live at 100 Main Street". I think you *might* say "I live at Number 7 Main Street" if the numbers were single-digit, but I've never lived anywhere with street numbers that low (and I live in a pretty small town by American standards). You could say "she lives in the third house on the right" if you already know which street, but probably there you wouldn't count up higher than maybe five. And in a particular *apartment building* you could say "the lady in Number/Unit/Apartment 7".

Comment: We use it in some cases... if it's a micro-community, like a group of cabins or apartments in a hotel, you might find this sort of thing... so "You're in cabin 5" or "She was staying in Bungalow 10 at the Roadside Motel".

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). It gives people a chance to review answers and reply so that you get accurate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a context in which the houses are in fact numbered in a small community, then yes, it is possible to refer to it as "house # 7". But the context has to be mentioned beforehand because, as far as I know, houses in the US are not numbered. So they are not referred to using a number. Instead, the specific address or some other characteristic is used to identify it. I imagine this is similar in other English speaking regions.

The usage of "house #7" is similar to the usage with apartments, hotel rooms, etc. For example,

> 1. John is in room number 105.

However, this is often shortened to

> 2. John is in room 105.

Similarly, I think

> 3. the lady who lives in house 7

is okay. I prefer *in* over *at* because *at* is used for specific street addresses in my mind:

> 4. The lady who lives at 123 Fake Street ...

But I imagine that *at* is okay in 3 too.

Is there a more concise way? Yes, I think using **from** can suggest the same meaning.

> The lady **from** house 7...

*From* is often used to indicate someone's origin, domain, home/hometown, etc.

> [from](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/from) preposition (ORIGIN)
>   used to show the origin of something or someone:
>   *I heard music coming from my room.*
>   *Someone from the bank just called.*
>   *Where are you from?*
>   *US Route 1 runs from Maine to Florida.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)